# Load local html file in android

Tags: android, android-studio

It works genymotion samsung galaxy s3 (api 18) but it doesn't work samsung galaxy s7 (api 25)

```
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com.tr");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com.tr");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would mind extending your answer bit more; for fellow programmers to understand; how exactly it helps to solve the problem.